# Group homomorphism $\mathbb Z^n\rightarrow \mathbb Z^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Let $\varphi:\mathbb Z^n\rightarrow \mathbb Z^n$ be an endomorphism of the additive group $\mathbb Z^n$ with $n\in \mathbb N$. Now I have to show that $\varphi$ is injective if and only if $\mathbb Z^n/ im (\varphi)$ is a finite group.

What i got so far:
I got the case n=1.
Let $\varphi(1)=x$ then $\varphi(z)=z*x$.

If $x=o$ then $im(\varphi)={0}\rightarrow \mathbb Z/ im (\varphi)=\mathbb Z$, infinite and clearly not injective.

If $x=m>0$ then  $im(\varphi)=m\mathbb Z\rightarrow \mathbb Z/ im (\varphi)=\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$, finite and clearly injective.

Now is it possible to prove it with induction?

Theres a tip which says "look at the induced homomorphism of Q-vectorspaces $\mathbb Q^n \rightarrow \mathbb Q^n$.

So how can I prove it with (1) induction and (2) with the tip?

What I got is that for the case n:
$\varphi$ is determined by $\varphi(e_i)=x_i$ where $e_i$ is the standard basis for $i\in I=\{1 \le i \le n \mid i\in \mathbb Z\}$. So $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ have to be linear independent for $\varphi$ to be injective. So in this case $im\varphi\cong\mathbb Z^n$

Comment: similar to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1091993/over-a-pid-textrankf-n-0-longleftrightarrow-textrankf-textrankn

Comment: I dont see how it would help me with my questions (1) or (2)

Comment: it is an alternate approach.  not using induction or $\mathbb Q$ vector space structures. I should have mentioned that with the link.

Comment: My first step would be to show that the group $\mathbb Z^n / im\left(\varphi\right)$ is finite if and only if it is torsion. (This holds more generally for any finitely generated abelian group.) Then, do some linear algebra.

Comment: By the way, "the induced homomorphism" uses the word "induced," but that doesn't mean you should use mathematical induction to prove the result. Indeed, I see no reason to apply mathematical induction to this problem at all.

Comment: I thought maybe it would help to use $\mathbb Z^n=\mathbb Z^{n-1}\oplus\mathbb Z$, (1) and (2) I've ment as separate questions.